# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::require_add

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to set up a basic Facebook application using PHP and an external .swf
this line 
`$user_id = $facebook->require_login();`

creates this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::require_add() in C:\httpdocs\facebook_application\index.php  on line 10`

I cannot find the cause of this error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using old versions.

Download the latest 'Facebook Platform' and also make sure you have the latest PHP5.

Answer (score 1):

I found out they changed everything lately.

```
$facebook =    
new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));      
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

This one worked with the new version!